# Require Git TFS pushes to link to work item

Tags: git, tfs, azure-devops

How can I assure that pushes to a git repository hosted on Visual Studio Online (i.e. `[company].visualstudio.com`) are linked to a valid work item (i.e. the commit message contains "#12345" where 12345 is a valid work item id)?

update hook? gated check in?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, on the service, there are no ways of doing this at this point in time.

With the on-premise version of TFS you could use a [server side hook](http://almsports.net/tfs-server-side-check-in-policy-for-git-repositories/1025/) to block the push, but since the service doesn't support server side hooks at this time that's not an option.

My suggestion would be to consider using cross-branch pull requests and as part of the review ensure that the check-in comment contains a #<workItem> reference in it.

Comment: That's correct. It is something we are looking to add.

Comment: @BuckHodges is there an update to this with the 2015 release?

Comment: We have branch policies in TFS 2015, but they aren't extensible yet. The best thing would be to write a server-side plugin (something you cannot do with VSO) using the server plugin (hook) facility that Richard referenced.